# Am I using instanceof "wrong"?

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

So in a simple game engine of mine I use an interface "UpdatedGameElement" to signal that an object having that interface has to be updated every frame through an implementation of an update() method.

Now in my "main"(not THE main) class I iterate through a list of GameElement 's and check if these are an instanceof UpdatedGameElement. If this is the case I cast them, and then call .update().

Now the thing is, I just read that using instanceof is usually a sign of bad coding; and in cases where classes are used as markers when they could be easily replaced with a variable, I agree. But I'm not so sure about my case.

I guess I could let the GameElement class implement UpdatedGameElement, and define a standard empty update() method that needs to be overridden to actually do something, but I'm not sure if and why that would be better than what I have now.

What would you say?

**Edit: some code from my main class:**

```
public void process()
{
    if (active)
    {
        for (GameElement GE: elements)
        {
            if (!GE.isToBeRemoved())
            {
                //Relevant part
                if (GE instanceof UpdatedGameElement)
                {
                    ((UpdatedGameElement) GE).update();
                }           
            }
            else
            {
                prepareRemoval(GE);
            }
        }  
        processRemovals();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just update all the GameElements? Or store them in their own list?

Comment: We need to see code. `instanceof` isn't necessarily bad, but this case suggests you might be better off holding a separate data structure that just has the updatable objects.

Comment: Are you sure it is necessary to keep all the GameElement's in the same list? Where are you creating/adding elements to the list `elements`?

Comment: Why doesn't every `GameElement` have an `update()`? If it's a no-op for some instances, how is it worse then the `instanceof` test. I think it's then a matter of opinion. The key question is this, does it work?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: The class GameElement is not updateable. So far a class has to implement UpdatedGameElement to be "updateable" (as in have a void update() ). And yes you are right: I could just let GameElement in on itself implement it, but I am just curious if you can use both approaches. (As for why: my current one would make classes more cleaner because they don't need to have a thousand methods subclasses MIGHT use.)

Also posted some code :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I was asking me the same thing. It is working indeed and I was really wondering if it's still "bad" coding style if used in this context.

Comment: @Christian: I kept all of them in one list because... I don't know actually. I guess I just like to make things as abstract as possible on the low end.
As for how I create and add such elements; A non abstract class extending GameElement has to be defined, instantiated and then added via elements.add().

Comment: There's a good place for such questions: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If use of the interface has no other reason than to add a marker plus the update method to GEs, and if the type UGE isn't used except after this single instanceof, then it is a weak reason for having these extra types. An abstract method in the base class forces the programmer to decide whether update needs to be coded for a particular subclass. If you forget the interface there's no alarm. There are a few subtle pro's and con's - not just the instanceof "smell".

Comment: @laune: Thank you for this precise and clear answer :) It really covered anything I wanted to know and it seemes you really understood the question. The part of the programmer having to decide sounds pretty convincing. I think I'm going to go with the abstract method.

Provide that text as a meta answer and you will get the green check mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the invitation if the OP:

If use of the interface has no other reason than to add a marker plus the update method to GEs, and if the type UGE isn't used except after this single instanceof, then it is a weak reason for having these extra types. ESpecially when the capability of being updated can be extended to all other GEs, where it is just a NOOP.

An abstract method in the base class forces the programmer to decide whether update needs to be coded for a particular subclass. This approach is rather "safe" from a "defensive design" point of view. But, of course, you write more code.

In contrast to the previous technique: If you forget the interface there's no alarm.

Also, if you code a NOOP update method in the base class and rely on programmers' alacrity to override where necessary: convenient, but risky when you forget to do it.

Summarizing: There are a few subtle pro's and con's - not just the instanceof "smell".

Comment: Perfect answer that covers every point I had questions about :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you mentioned that GameElement implements UpdatedGameElement, for now GameElement is the only class which is implementing UpdatedGameElement but it could be more in future. Also I hope you are aware that an interface cannot be instantiated thus you cannot create an instance of UpdatedGameElement thus in real the instances are created of the implementing classes of an interface. Thus during runtime when you create an instance of GameElement and assign it to UpdatedGameElement variable, that doesn't mean the instance is of type UpdatedGameElement now, its actually of type GameElement, now suppose that you have one more class implementing XYZElement implements UpdatedGameElement and create instance as below:

```
UpdatedGameElement ge = new GameElement();
UpdatedGameElement xyze = new XYZElement();
```

Do you think it good to use instance of check as below, as in either case it will be true and you never know which kind of instance ge and xyze are of.

```
if(ge instance of UpdatedGameElement)
instead one should always check for if(ge instance of GameElement)

Similarly for if(xyze instance of UpdatedGameElement)
instead one should always check for if(ge instance of XYZElement)

Hope this helps.
```

Comment: UpdatedGameElement is an interface. So every object implementing it is in fact of type UpdatedGameElement.

Comment: Also GameElement is abstract and supposed to be the base class for every other GameElement (Just like java's Object class). So there should not really be a conflict as you can't instantiate it and there is no other class that has something that is absolutely necessary for the engine but not in GameElement.

The thing I am asking is, if I can use my UpdatedGameElement interface as a marker in the circumstances I outlined.

I am sorry if I didn't outline that too well.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I could let the GameElement class implement
>   UpdatedGameElement, and define a standard empty update() method that
>   needs to be overridden to actually do something

Yes, you should definitely do it!

**Reason**: suppose in the future you'll need to implement another "updateable" class that extends `UpdatedGameElement` - consider the code changes you'll have to do in every place you've used `instanceof`...

Comment: I wouldn't have to make a change would I? The only use of UpdatedGameElement is to signal that there exists an update() method inside of the extending object that can be called. What that method does is defined within each individual class.

Comment: @JonasBartkowski you definitely *would* have to make a change unless the new class extends/implements `UpdatedGameElement`. Now, if the new class cannot extends/implements `UpdatedGameElement` (and there are at least couple of scenarios I can think of here where you won't be able to) - you'll have to add another `instanceof` check in every place in the code you used it.

Comment: Nah. It's supposed to do nothing if it does not implement UpdatedGameElement, so there exists no special behavior that would have to change if it doesn't.

Comment: @JonasBartkowski you didn't understand what I wrote - please read again

Comment: I think I read it right. In fact I already have 5 classes that extend UpdatedGameElement and I didn't need to change something.
The whole point of it being a marker is, that you won't have to do anything if you don't need the functionality.

Comment: If that's the case then you can roll with it. It's not what I would call a "clean" code, but you're not the first that uses an interface for the marker pattern (Serializable, Clonable etc.)